# need a href elemnt xpath for selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, xpath, href

I need to get an x path for a href element.

PFA the screenshot of html structure of the element.
element is a link "enter settlement details". Please help.
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Share `HTML` code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`//td[@class='small']/a[text()='Enter Settlement Details']`

For more right answer need see whole html-code of page or url-link of page.